# The reason for not showing the image in the first slider-carousel and its solution

Tags: html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I have a problem and tried all the slides but the problem is that the slider structure is shown but no pictures are shown
The only problem with the project is that the slider does not display the photos
I even used a slick slider but again I got the same problem
***The entire project is available at this link  [enter link description here](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8387631276/%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AC%DB%8C_%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7.rar.html)***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/css/swiper.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/reset-css.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>


</head>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                        <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2929290/pexels-photo-2929290.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3519656/pexels-photo-3519656.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3577391/pexels-photo-3577391.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3648850/pexels-photo-3648850.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="img/pin.png"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="img/bandicam 2019-08-02 16-25-03-568.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="img/bandicam 2019-08-02 17-07-24-742.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="img/bandicam 2019-08-02 17-08-20-757.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="img/bandicam 2020-02-05 14-48-02-096.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="img/bandicam 2019-07-29 20-39-41-098.jpg"></div>

                    </div>


                </div>



            </div>
        </section>
    </div>










    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                type: 'progressbar',
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoPlay:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check image src is correct?

Comment: @PrabuReddy  Yes sir,  i do inspect and click on the photos link the picture is displayed so it means the directions are correct

Comment: The Images are displaying for me.

Comment: @PrabuReddy I also uploaded the project file available through the link
So where can the problem be?